# Law of iterated expectations - an small exercise

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-expectation

From [edX MIT probability course - Widgets and Crates](https://courses.edx.org/courses/MITx/6.041x/1T2014/courseware/Unit_6_Further_topics_on_random_variables/Solved_problems43/):

---

Let $X_i$ be the number of widgets in a particular box $i$.
Let $N$ be the number of boxes in a crate.

Assume $X$ and $N$ are independent, both with expected value equal to 10 and variance equal to 16.

Evaluate the expected value of $T$, where $T$ is the total widgets in a crate.

---

Is it wrong to take the following aproach?

(1) Law of iterated expectations:
$$E[T] = E(E[T|N])$$

(2) Since in a crate there will be $X.N$ widgets, with both $X$ and $N$ random, $$E[E(T|N)]= E[N.X]$$

(3) Since $X$ and $N$ are independent, $$E[X.N] = E[X].E[N]=10^2=100$$

Thanks in advance,
SB

Comment: That's exactly how I'd do it. And you can compute the variance from the corresponding variance law. (Since this is essentially a routine bookwork problem, please add the `self-study` tag.)